# Exporting video layers for Premiere-DaVinci workflow

Tags: premiere, davinci-resolve, workflow

I am editing in Premiere, and sending an XML to a colourist working in DaVinci Resolve. We chose to colour after picture lock in order to reduce the colourist's workload. All of the tutorials I have seen recommend flattening the timeline into one video layer (eg. [There and Back Again - Frame.io](https://blog.frame.io/2019/11/04/premiere-to-davinci-resolve-roundtrip/)). However, I have several sections where the layers are neccesary, and their timing is important.  [This answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/25965/workflow-of-editing-in-premiere-and-color-grading-in-davinci) gives a brief overview of a possible workflow, but doesn't address the layers issue.
What are the best settings or workflow to make sure that the layers can be exported for DaVinci and maintain their place in the timeline?

Comment: It’s recommended to “flatten” all layers before attempting to conform, but it’s not strictly necessary.  Just make sure you export a reference video, and check all of the footage in resolve by importing it as an “offline reference video”. Resolve’s manual lists supported transformations, transitions, etc, but some things won’t translate 100%, like usually titles and fonts are a little off, re-timed clips might be off, etc. Fixing these issues is all part of the normal conform process. Premiere round tripping is a huge hassle that’s easily avoided by editing in resolve.

Answer (score 1):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdE7OIkgzRc) has a solution using Project Manager to export all clips individually, so that layers can be exported separately.

*File > Project manager* - Make sure your working sequence is selected.

Under *Resulting Project> Consolidate and Transcode*,  *source: Individual Clips*

Adjust the number of handles you want (extra frames on either side of the clip)

Choose your destination path, then OK to transcode.